# ionCube installation :: zend_extension problem xampp windows

Tags: php, xampp, ioncube

I trying to install ionCube on Xampp on Windows 10. Facing this error every time

ionCube Loader Wizard

**

> Please note that the following problem currently exists with the
>   ionCube Loader installation: The necessary zend_extension line could not be found in the configuration.

**

To use files that have been protected by the ionCube PHP Encoder, a component called the ionCube Loader must be installed.

At the current time the ionCube Loader requires PHP to be built with VC6/VC9/VC11/VC14/VC15. Your PHP software has been built using . Supported builds of PHP are available from PHP.net.

Comment: This simply means that you need the ionCube Loader dll for your combination of OS, architecture and PHP version to be on the machine and referenced from the primary php.ini file. For Windows, the best place to put the dll is in the modules extension folder as permissions are usually setup for PHP to be able to link dlls from there. If still stuck, you could create a ticket in the ionCube support system at https://support.ioncube.com

Answer (score 3):

> Important: IonCube Loader's latest version 10.3.9 supports only PHP 7.3. for Windows 10.
>   You have to download the XAMPP version for PHP 7.3 for Windows 10.
>   [Ioncube installed for PHP 7.4 version not working](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vg4ts.png)

Extract ioncube into htdocs ( XAMPP )
Open loader-wizard.php from ioncube folder >>
[loader-wizard.php Instractions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UMTMI.png)

> Copy `ioncube_loader_win_7.3.dll` to `C:/xampp/php/ext/` >> [Test loader](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WTcaS.png)

Follow instructions Edit `php.ini`
[Loader not installed. RESTART XAMPP APACHE SERVER](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TYcXC.png)

[ionCube loader version 10.3.9 for PHP 7.3 is Installed Successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SYAzJ.png)

Answer (score 0):

Copy loader-wizard.php in htdocs folder then run it, it will give you all instruction you need to follow. Follow them as instructed. I have struggled to install ioncube loader for more than 4 days searching, after running loader-wizard.php it gave me everything I need to know.

Note:
You must use the right loader version as your php version. eg. for php7.2 loader should be ioncube_loader_win_7.2.dll

The link to download correct loader is provided in loader-wizard.php.

That`s everything you need.

Comment: I am using ioncube 10.2, my php version is 7.4 so my loader is ioncube_loader_win_7.4.dll and it works perfect.